# ng-show ng-hide: What qualifies as truthy value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am building an application in angular and using cookies to set the value, so that when page refresh happens persistence should be there i.e. If I am logged in I should see Profile and Logout page and If I am not logged in I should see Register/LogIn page. 
Here is the code.

```
app.controller("NavCntrl", function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, $cookies)
{
    $scope.logout = function()
    {
        console.log("Logout");
        //$rootScope.currentUser=undefined;
        $cookies.put('loggedIn', "");
        //$location.url('/home');
    }
 $scope.loggedIn = $cookies.get('loggedIn');
 if($scope.loggedIn == "true")
 {
    $scope.loggedOut = "";
 }
 else
 {
    $scope.loggedOut = "true";
 }
});
```

and the html looks following

```
<nav ng-controller ="NavCntrl" class="navbar navbar-default" >
<div >
    <a href="/home" class="navbar-brand" >Home</a>
    <span ng-show = "loggedOut">
        <a href="/login" class="navbar-brand" >Login</a> 
        <a href="/register" class="navbar-brand">Register</a>  
    </span> 
    <span ng-show = "loggedIn">
        <a href="/logout" ng-click=logout() class="navbar-brand">Logout</a> 
        <a href="/profile" class="navbar-brand">Profile</a>
    </span>
</div> 
</nav>
```

Now whenever I login I set this `$cookies.put("loggedIn", true);`

The behavior I saw while debugging the Angular was that at times the value being evaluated is correct but the HTML is not getting updated as follows. 
I am considering that my understanding of truthy expressions is wrong. **What qualifies an expression to be set as true?** As I see in examples some people just equate it to blank string to deem it false, or sometime they give boolean value? **How do I correct the behavior of my application?** .

Comment: The same expressions that qualify to be true in js, qualifies to be true in angularJS. Remember: AngularJS expressions are just Javascript expressions. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

From the comment: *The same expressions that qualify to be true in js, qualifies to be true in angularJS. Remember: AngularJS expressions are just Javascript expressions.*

Also, looks like you're placing a boolean value as a string. Why don't you use true/false instead? Something like this:

```
app.controller("NavCntrl", function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, $cookies)
{
    $scope.logout = function()
    {
        console.log("Logout");
        //$rootScope.currentUser=undefined;
        $cookies.put('loggedIn', false);
        //$location.url('/home');
    }
    $scope.loggedIn = $cookies.get('loggedIn');
    if($scope.loggedIn)
    {
        $scope.loggedOut = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.loggedOut = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: For `$scope.loggedOut=""` . Why does it qualify as false for ng-show? as you are setting one as `true` and other as `""`

Comment: Because in javascript ```"" == false // It's true```

Comment: Well I applied the fix. It still doesn't work. I mean the ng-show is unable to update it. Even after logging in I am seeing the login/ Register Screen . What else could be the problem?

Comment: wrap the function in quotes just to be sure: ```<a href="/logout" ng-click="logout()" class="navbar-brand">Logout</a> ```

Comment: Now, I don't see where the cookie loggedIn is being set. Mind explaining that?

Comment: I noticed one more more thing. That the html file that I included is my index.html . and everywhere I am giving $location.url('/home'). So that after login it redirects to the home page. So if after login when my address bar reads. http://localhost:8082/home and I hit refresh I get the correct value. i.e If I am logged in I get logout/profile page or If I am logged out Login/Register page. So Long story short It requires a full page refresh in order for these changes to show. Why is that? If you can't understand let me know. I'll try explaining it in a better way

Comment: Would you reflect the code you currently have in your post so I can investigate a bit more? I didn't understand what you just said probably because I'm not seeing too much code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is kinda with your logic to begin with.  If you want to stick to the cookie idea, I would do something like this...

```
app.controller("NavCntrl", function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, $cookies)
{
    $scope.loggedIn = $cookies.get('loggedIn');

    $scope.logout = function()
    {
        console.log("Logout");
        $cookies.put('loggedIn', 'false');
        $scope.loggedIn = $cookies.get('loggedIn');
    };

    $scope.login = function()
    {
        console.log("Login");
        $cookies.put('loggedIn', 'true');
        $scope.loggedIn = $cookies.get('loggedIn');
    };

});
```

Then in your html just use this logic...

```
<nav ng-controller ="NavCntrl" class="navbar navbar-default" >
<div >
    <a href="/home" class="navbar-brand" >Home</a>
    <span ng-show = "loggedIn == 'false'">
        <a href="/login" ng-click=login() class="navbar-brand" >Login</a> 
        <a href="/register" class="navbar-brand">Register</a>  
    </span> 
    <span ng-show = "loggedIn == 'true'">
        <a href="/logout" ng-click=logout() class="navbar-brand">Logout</a> 
        <a href="/profile" class="navbar-brand">Profile</a>
    </span>
</div> 
</nav>
```

Comment: I noticed one more more thing. That the html file that I included is my index.html . and everywhere I am giving `$location.url('/home')`. So that after login it redirects to the home page. So if after login when my address bar reads. `http://localhost:8082/home` and I hit refresh I get the correct value.  i.e If I am logged in I get logout/profile page or If I am logged out Login/Register page. So Long story short __It requires a full page refresh in order for these changes to show__. Why is that? If you can't understand let me know. I'll try explaining it in a better way

Comment: Without seeing how you have put your app together, there could be a million things wrong, so it's kinda hard to guess.  That said, you could try replacing $scope with $rootScope for your loggedIn variable to make it available to all of your controllers.

Answer (score -1):

You are using string value for `"true"` which is not the same as using `boolean` value `true`

Comment: But the OP's making an expression that evaluates to a boolean, anyway